# Pushing an existing Heroku project from a new machine

Tags: deployment, heroku

I am trying to push a project to Heroku via "git push heroku" but keep getting the error "Your key with fingerprint XXXX is not authorized to access..."  The project is already in existence and has been pushed multiple times from other machines."  I already had an SSH key setup on this machine but when I added it via "heroku keys:add" I got the before mentioned error.  Trying to start fresh, I've done the following:

heroku logout
heroku login (with my credentials that work on Heroku)
heroku keys:remove
heroku keys (shows no keys are there)
ssh-keygen -t rsa (to generate a new key)
heroku keys:add (successfully added newly generated key)
heroku keys (I see my added key)

Then after doing all this, if I run the "git push heroku" I still get the error message about my key not having access.  I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I cannot figure it out.  Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Chris